# Docker container in EC2 is unable to write data into AWS S3 through AWS SDK

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker-machine, access-denied

I have a docker machine running on AWS EC2 instance. It suppose to upload data to S3 via SDK client.

1. The docker machine is created in EC2 instance and using following command

```
--driver amazonec2 \
--amazonec2-open-port ${open-port} \
--amazonec2-region ${region} \
--amazonec2-access-key ${access-key} \
--amazonec2-secret-key ${secret-key} \
--amazonec2-instance-type ${instance_type} \
--amazonec2-ami ${this.ami} \
--amazonec2-security-group ${security_group_name} \
--swarm \
--swarm-discovery token://${swarm_join_token} \
--swarm-addr ${ip_address};
```

2. I created IAM user with S3fullAccess and also allowed public access
   [S3 full access screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTOdl.png)

[public access screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ZhO.png)

3. The S3 bucket policy is

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policyxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It keeps showing `error: AccessDenied: Access Denied`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your bucket policy does not allow a public access, which is bad idea anyway with `s3:*` permissions. What is `arn:aws:iam::xxx`? Is it instance role?

Comment: hi @Marcin, I just tried with public access `"Principle": "*"`, but got access denied too.
`arn:aws:iam::xxx` is an iam user with AmazonS3FullAccess and I started the ec2 instance with that access key id and secret key.
Anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access to S3 from the container running on EC2 instance is not dictated by your IAM user credentials. Instead you should setup [IAM role/profile for the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) with S3 permissions, and then provide the role/profile name using option for your `docker-machine`:

```
--amazonec2-iam-instance-profile
```

The permissions of the instance will be available inside the container if you use **AWS CLI or SDK**.

Instead of bucket policy, its easier to add **S3 permissions to the instance role**.